# What is this hardware "PS 3.3V" which is showing critical?

Tags: linux

PS 3.3V          | 18h | lcr |  7.15 | 2.80 Volts

```
MLB TEMP 1       | 21h | ok  |  7.1 | 43 degrees C
MLB TEMP 2       | 22h | ok  |  7.2 | 40 degrees C
MLB TEMP 3       | 23h | ok  |  7.3 | 37 degrees C
MLB TEMP 4       | 24h | ok  |  7.4 | 36 degrees C
MLB TEMP 5       | 25h | ok  |  7.5 | 35 degrees C
MLB TEMP 6       | 26h | ok  |  7.6 | 35 degrees C
MLB TEMP 7       | 27h | ok  |  7.7 | 33 degrees C
MLB TEMP 8       | 28h | ok  |  7.8 | 33 degrees C
MLB TEMP 9       | 29h | ok  |  7.9 | 34 degrees C
MLB TEMP 10      | 2Ah | ok  |  7.10 | 33 degrees C
MB Ambient       | 91h | ok  |  7.11 | 27 degrees C
CPU 1 Temp       | 61h | ok  |  3.1 | 25 degrees C
CPU 2 Temp       | 62h | ok  |  3.2 | 26 degrees C
CPU1 PECI ABS    | 65h | ok  |  3.3 | 50 degrees C
CPU2 PECI ABS    | 66h | ok  |  3.4 | 49 degrees C
CPU1 Status      | 41h | ok  |  3.5 | 
CPU2 Status      | 42h | ok  |  3.6 | 
VCORE1           | 51h | ok  |  3.7 | 0.80 Volts
VCORE2           | 52h | ok  |  3.8 | 0.80 Volts
STBY 5V          | 11h | ok  |  7.12 | 4.86 Volts
PS 5V            | 15h | ok  |  7.13 | 5.02 Volts
PS 12.XV         | 16h | ok  |  7.14 | 12.09 Volts
PS 3.3V          | 18h | lcr |  7.15 | 2.80 Volts -----> showing critical
PS 1.1V          | 1Ch | ok  |  7.16 | 1.09 Volts
SYSTEM FAN 1     | 01h | ok  | 29.1 | 6960 RPM
SYSTEM FAN 2     | 02h | ok  | 29.2 | 6960 RPM
SYSTEM FAN 3     | 03h | ok  | 29.3 | 6960 RPM
SYSTEM FAN 4     | 05h | ok  | 29.5 | 6960 RPM
SYSTEM FAN 5     | 06h | ok  | 29.6 | 6880 RPM
PSU1 Status      | 31h | ok  | 10.1 | Presence detected
PSU2 Status      | 32h | ok  | 10.2 | Presence detected
PSU Power In     | 37h | ok  | 10.3 | 94 Watts
PSU Redundancy   | 3Fh | ok  | 10.4 | Fully Redundant
ACPI Pwr State   | 73h | ok  |  7.17 | Legacy ON state
SEL Fullness     | 7Ah | ok  |  7.18 | 
PEF Action       | 71h | ok  |  7.19 | 
Watchdog2        | 72h | ok  |  7.20 | 
Memory           | 7Bh | ok  |  7.21 | 
PCI BUS          | 7Ch | ok  |  7.22 |
```

Comment: You have four secondary power supplies for different voltages. The ones to 5, 12, and 1.1 volts are all within 1% of nominal. The 3.3 volt one is running 15% below nominal voltage. It is dying on its feet. Whatever runs off 3.3V (probably CPUs) is about to not work any more. No idea what that would be, because you don't say anything about the hardware.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant ZT SYSTEMS (Model: Z1100S)

Comment: @AndyDalton Noted. Thanks!

Comment: Could be anything from "wrong scale factor in driver" to "in this hardware, something else is connected to this sensor, so 2.8V is actually ok" to "in this hardware, nothing is connected there, and the reading is spurious" to "it's critical, but whatever is connected to it is tolerant enough to keep running". If you really want to know, identify the sensor chip, find it on the motherboard, and trace connections, if you can (difficult with multilayer...). If PS means "Power Supply", you can also check with a multimeter on the power supply connector.

Comment: I found ZT Systems, and they make high-end "hyperscale" data centre machines -- rack-mounted servers. I don't see a Z1100S, but their site shows rooms full of wardrobes. You have to have a support regime in place for this, probably remote 24/7 monitoring. This thing has 15 temperature sensors, five fans, dualled power supplies. Call engineering. If you are engineering, call Ghostbusters.